# Question about prime numbers: how to find $\pi(x)$ quickly?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any other method or trick to find pi(x)[no. of primes upto x]other than the formula given by Euler..? (The [other question is on prime arithmetic progressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267578/question-about-primes).)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find number of prime numbers up to to N?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264544/how-to-find-number-of-prime-numbers-up-to-to-n)

Comment: There is a great deal of literature on computing the prime counting function $\pi(x)$.  Please start with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_.CF.80.28x.29) and a search of previous Math.SE Questions on this subject.  If you have a more specific question to ask, you can edit and perhaps the current post can be reconsidered.

Answer (score 3):

Values of π(n) have been calculated up to n = $10^{26}$. For a simple method that is significantly faster than just finding all the primes using a sieve and counting, you can look up Legendre's method for example here: https://programmingpraxis.com/2011/07/22/counting-primes-using-legendres-formula/  Legendre's method is quite simple. Faster methods run in $O (n^{2/3+\epsilon})$.

The "trick" is to avoid actually finding all the primes, if all you want to know is how many there are.