# What's the maximum length of a sequence of equidistant primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Is there any work done on prime numbers which are equidistant means like (11,17,23,29)..?what is the maximum length of such group means the group of primes which are equidistant...like the group I have mentioned is of length 4.

Comment: Please not not repeat [old questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267482/questions-about-prime-numbers)! And yes, google for Terry Tao's Theorem.

Comment: Also, see the Wikipedia article about [primes in arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression).

Comment: Dietrich means [the Green-Tao theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green-Tao_theorem). The theorem states that there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions consisting of prime numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [the Green-Tao theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green-Tao_theorem), there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions consisting of prime numbers.

The first known case of 26 primes in an arithmetic progression (found in 2010) is

$$
43\,142\,746\,595\,714\,191 + 5\,283\,234\,035\,979\,900 \cdot n, 
\quad\mbox{ for } n = 0 \ldots25.
$$

Comment: Ohh..chain of 26 primes..I was working on primes and I found chain of 7 primes nd I was happy thinking I had discovered something.. bt this shows me I was too wrong..uff..bt thanks for your help.

Comment: @omkarGirkar You are welcome! So can you accept this answer? You might earn a "Scholar" badge by accepting. :)

Comment: Yes.. I read more about it on wiki too..it's amazing.

Comment: Oh..I was unknown about it.