# Making sure $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, coprime

I came across this interesting problem in the Olympiad Maths challenge practice problem, and it is really fascinating:

*Some $n$ numbers are selected randomly from the integers $1$ to $420$. $2$ integers $a$ and $b$ are chosen from that set of $n$ numbers such that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Find the minimum value of $n$ that ensures there exists $2$ such integers $a$ and $b$*

If you don't know what relatively prime is it means that the two numbers don't share any factors greater than one (therefore the HCF of $a$ and $b$ is $1$)

My evaluation is that two numbers is relatively prime if at least $1$ of the number is prime, therefore not sharing any factors with the other number except $1$ (since primes have the factors only $1$ and itself).

This evaluation should work! UNLESS the second number is the prime number doubled, or tripled, or quadrupled, etc.

First of all, I have to deal with the fact that we're randomly picking from the set of $1$ to $420$, so I have to find the number of prime numbers between $1$ and $420$.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264544/how-to-find-number-of-prime-numbers-up-to-to-n) almost answers my prime question, but I tried $\pi(420) $ and I got about $69$ (Very nice coincidence by the way, $69420$). And the pool of answers is no near that (Multiple choice: $208, 211, 215, 220$) So I am now stuck in this hole precisely here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily solved by using the [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Observe that if two numbers are consecutive, then they are relatively primes. Now one can pick every second number starting from $2$ till $420$ (all the even numbers). Now as every alternate number is picked already, the pigeonhole principle guarantees that picking any more numbers would result in a pair of consecutive numbers, which will be relatively prime.

$\therefore $ The minimum value of $n$ to guarantee that there will be $2$ relatively prime numbers in the chosen $n$ numbers is $211$.

Note: It is not necessary that one of the numbers is prime for the pair to be relatively prime. For example $(9,14)$ is such a pair of relatively prime numbers with none of them being prime. Any numbers of the form $a=p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ and $b=q_1^{b_1}\cdot q_2^{b_2}\cdots q_m^{b_m}$ are relatively prime $(p_i\neq q_i\space \forall\ i\in \mathbb N)$ with none of them being primes.

Comment: @Chrystomath It asks for the minimum value of $n$ to 'guarantee' the existance of two relatively prime number. If it had not been for the 'guarantee' condition, one could've easily found any two primes among $1$ to $420$ and given the value $n=2$, which makes the question completely useless.

Comment: I’m not convinced by your answer. Your just proved that $n=211$ is a *sufficient* value that we can find a and b. But you don’t know whether an $m<n$ exists or not and also satisfies that we can find a and b

Comment: @Chrystomath Take the numbers ${2,4,6,8,\cdots, 22}$, and find any pair of co prime numbers in them.

Comment: @NN2 for any $n<211$, I can take the numbers $\{2,4,6,8,\cdots, 2(n-1),2n\}$ and no two of them will be relatively prime. Once $n>211$, at least two of them will be consecutive, hence co prime. Thus the minimum $n$ is $211$, this is the whole premise of pigeonhole principle

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thanks